# iPad Catelog Application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova, appcelerator

I want to create an Ipad/iPhone app that will act as a catalog to allow users to select items and send request to the company to process

1. User Downloads the App
2. Login into the app
3. Downloads the available Categories and Items ( Text details and 2 size of images)
4. Should be able to browse offline
5. While sending the request for the items needs to be online but can select the options offline.
6. Should be able to upload an image/design to the order list and add remarks.

My Main question is - Can we download data from the server like images and cache in locally into the local database and directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can save whatever info you want into a local sandboxed, file system.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

It looks like the PhoneGap Framework will also allow local storage.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap

Comment: Thank you :) i am new to iOS programing

Comment: just a quick question. can i use PhoneGap and achieve the same too ?